# Block browser addons with JS?

Tags: javascript, browser, browser-addons

I notice that LOTS of people (majority that use IE) have gazillions of adware browser addons and many of them replace text on my site with links to ads etc.

This looks like I am advertising spammy stuff to the end user and I was wondering if there was anything that could be done to stop this?

Maybe some special JS code that could block any changes being made? I dunno? Is this impossible, or are there any solutions?

Thanks

Mike

Comment: As a user I would expect my browser add-ons to have priority over whatever individual websites are trying to do. As a web developer I can understand not wanting your page changed, especially not to introduce advertising, but that type of add-on isn't targeting only your page so the user would be used to seeing the same thing on _every_ page...

Comment: Maybe just detect these changes, and pops up a warning box telling the user to uninstall their adware?